# How can I verify if TLS 1.2 is supported on a remote web server from the RHEL/CentOS shell?

Tags: linux, centos, openssl, tls

I'm on CentOS 5.9.

I'd like to determine from the linux shell if a remote web server specifically supports TLS 1.2 (as opposed to TLS 1.0).  Is there an easy way to check for that?

I'm not seeing a related option on `openssl` but perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You should use openssl s_client, and the option you are looking for is -tls1_2.

An example command would be:

`openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2`

If you get the certificate chain and the handshake you know the system in question supports TLS 1.2. If you see don't see the certificate chain, and something similar to "handshake error" you know it does not support TLS 1.2.  You can also test for TLS 1 or TLS 1.1 with -tls1 or tls1_1 respectively.

Comment: And keep in mind that you'll have to use a version of OpenSSL which does TLS 1.2, and that means CentOS 5 is right out.

Comment: Does not work on Mac OS X  10.11

Comment: Michael Hampton, only OOB setups:

[me@server][~]                                                                                                                   cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.11 (Final)
                                                                                                                                                  [me@server][~]                                                                                                                                openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015

;)

Comment: @Quanlong homebrew has openssl v1.0.2. Install it then run it with `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/bin/openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -tls1_2`

Comment: It works fine after `brew upgrade openssl`

Comment: Worked as per expectation on OpenSuse Tumbleweed. Thanks

Comment: See also this very good answer to similar question: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/169738/60157

Answer (score 117):

Also you can list all supported ciphers using:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.example.com
```

And then check the output. If it's supported you'll get something like this:

```
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
```

Comment: Got a really hard time trying to make this third party script work. Wrote mine for people interested : [here](https://github.com/xlucas/ssl-inspector).

Comment: It worked great for me.

Comment: As on date, nmap doesn’t support TLS1.3, so this command will not help if you want to check for TLS1.3 availability on the web server side.  Otherwise for upto version 1.2 , this solution is working fine.

Comment: I'm not an expert with nmap, but I think you should probably use `-Pn`, in case the server isn't pingable.

Comment: nmap now supports TLSv1.3 https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/1348. validated on version 7.94